# Is it possible? group by Visit.VstMobile having ( (count(Visit.VstMobile)) >1 for multiple options

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, having-clause, multiple-conditions

Let me know if this is possible in mysql query:
I have referred more options in stackoverflow.

**group by Visit.VstMobile 
having ( (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=0 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=10) or (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=10 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=20))**

I have a range selection and multiple select like:

**[0-10]**

**[10-20]**

**[20+]**

I can select multiple options in above dropdown.

based on this post value I have to form the query in having clause. Please let me know if any other option.

This is my Query:

`select Distinct(Visit.VstMobile) as mobile, count(VstMobile) as cnt from Visit
        inner join centertemp on Visit.RegistrationCentreCode=centertemp.SysNo
        inner join patient on Visit.VstPatCode=patient.Patcode
        inner join result on result.TrJobCode=Visit.VstCode
        inner join Test on Test.TestCode=result.TrTestCode
        inner join Param on Param.ParamCode=result.TrParamCode 
----[some where conditions]----
group by Visit.VstMobile 
having ( (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=0 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=10) or (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=10 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=20))`

-- not returning a single row.

Comment: Most things are possible. Beyond that, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: your `having clause` is equivalent to `having count(Visit.VstMobile)<=20`

Comment: It is possible. Distinct is not necessary. Your inner joins with YOUR data do not support a row coming back

Comment: `having ( (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=0 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=10) or (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=10 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=20))` condition is not returning any row in above query where is the problem. @Strawberry

Comment: Without a data source we can't really tell you why isn't not working with your data.

Comment: Your entire having clause can be changed to `HAVING COUNT(visit.vstMobile) BETWEEN 0 AND 20`. Edit: I just realized this was posted before, but here's an alternative.

Comment: to rule out the 'having' conditions, remove those and execute the query with just the group by. If it is still not working, try posting a sample dataset using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: As Alan mentioned. Enable us to help you

Comment: please go through this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fb91/3  i have created small schema to understand. @Drew Pierce

Comment: 1. Your multiple conditions are you say,,does that mean you select 2 or 3 ranges or something else that i dont understand (it is vague)

Comment: 2. Why are there overlaps on ranges?

Comment: 3. Are you hell-bent on solving this with a `having` or do you just want a solution? I mean is it academic or business need (the former is not too appealing

Comment: 4. What are desired results were someone to look at your fiddle based on various range selections? Until the desired are documented it would be hard to start

Comment: Thanks @Drew Pierce, It is a goddamn urgent. Please tell me where you haven't understand.

Comment: The 4 above i listed

Comment: for point-1, If client need it then it is must. user may select on his own 2-3 ranges. for  point-2 ,If  over laps are there on ranges then pls explain how can we over come on this. for point-3,  If have any other option i'll definitely solve it.(as i have no option other than having clause).  for point-4, dont go for sqlfiddle, go for query above mentioned. @Drew Pierce.

Comment: no solution for this?

Comment: from your fiddle, I understand that the number ranges may vary. so the number conditions in the having clause may vary. So the best option would be dynamically write the query in code, based on the user input and execute them. that is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, I understand that the number of ranges may vary. so the number of conditions in the having clause may vary. 
So the simplest option would be dynamically write the query in code, based on the user input and execute the query. here's a possible solution:

```
<?php
$range1 = "2-5"; //get from user 
$range2 = "5-10"; //get from user 
$range3 = ""; //get from user

$sql = "SELECT VstMobile, count(VstMobile) as cnt FROM Venkatesh group by VstMobile ";

//all ranges are optional, hence check if we need having clause
if($range1 != "" or $range2 == "" or $range3 ==""){
    $sql = $sql . " having ("

    if($range1 != ""){
        $val1 = explode('-',$range1);
        $sql = $sql . " (count(VstMobile) >=". $val1[0] . "and count(VstMobile) <= ".$val1[1].")";
    }
    if($range2 != ""){
        $val2 = explode('-',$range2);
        //check previous condition string exists before adding 'or' condition
        if($range1 != ""){
            $sql .= " or ";
        }
        $sql = $sql . " (count(VstMobile) >=". $val2[0] . "and count(VstMobile) <= ".$val2[1].")";
    }
    if($range3 != ""){
        $val3 = explode('-',$range3);
        //check previous condition string exists before adding 'or' condition
        if($range2 != "" or $range1 != ""){
            $sql .= " or ";
        }
        $sql = $sql . " (count(VstMobile) >=". $val3[0] . "and count(VstMobile) <= ".$val3[1].")";
    }
    $sql = $sql . " )"          
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
```

I'm not very good at php, but since you tagged php I made an attempt, so forgive syntax errors if any and I hope you understand the basic idea of it.

**Edit from Drew**

```
CREATE TABLE Venkatesh (VstMobile varchar(10));



INSERT INTO Venkatesh (`VstMobile`) VALUES ('1234567890'),('1234567890'),('1223345547'),('1223345547');
('9876543210'),('9876543210'),('1223345547'),('1223345547');
('9876543210'),('9876543210'),('9876543210'),('9876543201');
('9876543201'),('9876543201');



// select vstmobile,count(*) 
// from Venkatesh 
// group by vstmobile



SELECT VstMobile, 
count(VstMobile) as cnt 
FROM Venkatesh 
group by VstMobile 
having (
(count(VstMobile)>=0 and count(VstMobile) <=10) 

or (count(Vstmobile)>=10 and count(VstMobile)<=20) 

or (count(Vstmobile)>=20));

-- counts for all



SELECT VstMobile, 
count(VstMobile) as cnt 
FROM Venkatesh 
group by VstMobile 
having (

(count(VstMobile)>=0 and count(VstMobile) <=10) 

or (count(Vstmobile)>=20));

-- counts for all



SELECT VstMobile, 
count(VstMobile) as cnt 
FROM Venkatesh 
group by VstMobile 
having (
(count(Vstmobile)>=20));

-- 0 rows
```

works great what is the **problem** with it?

Comment: Morning Ven. Please let Alan know if you need more help. Just woke up can take a look. Thx Alan

Comment: Because no GUI shown and explanations from Ven doesnt exactly clear it up, I am assuming the user can have 1 2 or 3 ranges active

Comment: In the sqlfiddle he mentioned "ranges may be posted from user, both or all three ranges or only one" so my snippet is based on that. it will work for 0,1,2 and 3 ranges.

Comment: I appreciate your work @Alan. i know this thing to get values from user contains all or one or two. but problem is having clause doesn't return any records from your solutions.--Thanks for your try.

Comment: Thanks for waking me Up @Drew.

Comment: I'll take a look it is prob close

Comment: I cant get either of your fiddles to load. Can someone edit bottom of question with a create table and data load or a fiddle that loads

Comment: No need:  Clear note: i have this `having ( (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=0 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=10) or (count(Visit.VstMobile)>=10 and count(Visit.VstMobile)<=20))` in my query will this run? i have multiple conditions. there is no way! @Drew

Comment: I just need data and table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82089/discussion-between-venkatesh-badigeru-and-drew-pierce).